# TypeError: $(...).offset(...) is undefined

Tags: jquery

I'm getting this error

> TypeError: $(...).offset(...) is undefined

with the arrow pointing to the $.

I've looked at the questions that popped up when I typed this error into the title, but I didn't get a solution.

Here is my jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
if(window.location.href.indexOf("#") > -1)
{
    var pieces = window.location.href.split(/[\s_]+/);
    var section = pieces[pieces.length-1];
    var element_to_scroll_to = $('#' + section);
    var navbar_height = parseInt($('.navbar').css('height').replace('px', ''));
    animate_scroll(element_to_scroll_to, navbar_height, 25);
}
});

function animate_scroll (element, variable, offset) {
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $(element).offset().top - variable - offset

    }, 600);

}
```

and this is the order my js files are

```
{{ HTML::script('js/jquery-1.10.2.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('js/jquery-ui.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('js/bootstrap.min.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('js/wow.min.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('js/jquery.superslides.min.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('js/slick.min.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('js/modernizr.custom.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('js/classie.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('js/elastic_grid.min.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('js/webkrunch_portfolio.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('js/main.js') }}
```

Comment: It doesn't know what `$(element)` is. You never defined it. Try using just `element`. So basically `scrollTop: element.offset().top - variable - offset`

Comment: Chances are $(element) doesn't exist in the DOM. Try checking $(element).length first.

Comment: shouldn't that whole scrollTop thing be enclosed with a function {}?

Comment: first things first - learn to use the console in [Chrome Developer Tools](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/part1/)... with a simple `console.log(element, $(element))` inside your `animate_scroll()` function, you'd be able to debug this yourself

Answer (score 2):

So, its quite easy to break down whats happening here.

You are utilizing that function called `animate_scroll` and calling the parameter `element` as `element_to_scroll_to`.

With this in mind, `element_to_scroll_to` is already calling `jQuery` via:

```
$('#' + section);
```

So when `animate_scroll()` is called, its seeing this:

```
$('html, body').stop().animate({
    scrollTop: $($('#' + section)).offset().top - variable - offset
}, 600);
// Notice the dual call of jQuery
```

You should be able to simply call `element` instead of redefining `jQuery` again, like so:

```
$('html, body').stop().animate({
    scrollTop: element.offset().top - variable - offset
}, 600);
```

EDIT:

So, if you are still getting an error, the problem lies further back. Here are the steps I would take to identify the issue.

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("#") > -1) // Perhaps this is not returning > -1
{
    var pieces = window.location.href.split(/[\s_]+/); // Perhaps this is not creating an array to pull from
    var section = pieces[pieces.length-1]; // Perhaps the last element doesn't exist in the first place based on the above tests
    var element_to_scroll_to = $('#' + section);
    var navbar_height = parseInt($('.navbar').css('height').replace('px', ''));
    animate_scroll(element_to_scroll_to, navbar_height, 25);

    console.log(pieces);
    console.log(section);
    console.log(element_to_scroll_to);
}
```

}

To test the above, I would run simple console tests such as:

```
console.log(pieces);
console.log(section);
console.log(element_to_scroll_to);
```

view the console after adding those at the end of your `if` statement and it should clarify further which section is undefined.

Comment: When I do that I get kind of the same error but now it says `TypeError: element.offset(...) is undefined
 

scrollTop: element.offset().top - variable - offset`

Comment: So keep back-tracing until you find out where the issue is. I will edit the post with things to start looking backward for.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should make a test to the element scrolling.

Your code become like

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
if(window.location.href.indexOf("#") > -1)
{
    var pieces = window.location.href.split(/[\s_]+/);
    var section = pieces[pieces.length-1];
    var element_to_scroll_to = $('#' + section);
    if(element_to_scroll_to.length) {
    var navbar_height =      
    parseInt($('.navbar').css('height').replace('px', ''));
    animate_scroll(element_to_scroll_to, navbar_height, 25);
    }
}
});

function animate_scroll (element, variable, offset) {
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $(element).offset().top - variable - offset

    }, 600);

}
```